# error 1292, Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ''

Tags: mysql, mariadb

im try to insert data to table `order` but allows im getting error

**[22007][1292] Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ''**

```
INSERT INTO `order`
SET `order`.customerId  = '9e1c8915-c60c-407e-8d34-9fefdffd5ebd',
`order`.orderStatus = 0,
`order`.address     = 'fafff5a9-a65b-42ae-87f5-b9f1ef99de37';
```

this is my table DDL

```
create table `order`(
id          int(11) unsigned default 0                   not null primary key,
date        timestamp        default current_timestamp() not null,
customerId  varchar(50)                                  not null,
orderStatus int              default 0                   not null,
address     varchar(50)                                  not null,
createDate  timestamp        default current_timestamp() not null,
modifyDate  timestamp        default current_timestamp() not null on update current_timestamp(),
constraint temporder_address_id_fk
    foreign key (address) references address (id),
constraint temporder_customer_id_fk
    foreign key (customerId) references customer (id)
)
charset = utf8mb3;

create index id
on `order` (id);

create definer = root@localhost trigger tg_order_insert
before insert
on `order`
for each row
SET NEW.id = IF(NEW.id='', CONCAT('ORD', LPAD(myFunc('order'), 5, '0')), NEW.id);
```

this myFunc method

```
create
   definer = root@localhost function myFunc(seqname varchar(5)) returns int unsigned
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO sequences
   VALUES (seqname, LAST_INSERT_ID(1))
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE val=LAST_INSERT_ID(val + 1);
   RETURN LAST_INSERT_ID();
END;
```

im using mariadb version: 10.6.4-MariaDB

any idea please ?

Comment: Question 1 does 'order'.id need to be defined as auto_increment?
Question 2 Would you agree customer_id  VARCHAR(50) in charset of utf8mb3 has a limit of less than 17 characters in data length?  The id you are trying to stuff into the size is more than permitted.

Comment: answer Q1 yes i want auto_increment, 
answer Q2 i set the collection to utf8_general_ci from long time but later i saw the after update the utf8_collection_ci has change when i create the schema its change the collection to utf8_mb3 @WilsonHauck

Answer (score 0):

- `order.id` is `INT`
- `NEW.id = CONCAT('ORD', ...)` is trying to store a string into that INT.

Which datatype do you need??

Comment: sorry i was not observing the datatype maybe because of that i will try again
thank you for this answer